Error:- Exception - syntax error, unexpected token "&lt;", expecting end of file. Moodle not woking

Error:- Exception - syntax error, unexpected token "<", expecting end of file. Moodle not woking.
Site administration and all the options got stucked here and not working at all.
This problem started arising since I have installed Attendance plugin.
Tried those methods mentioned below but still not workinng.
Log in to Moodle as an admin user:- Its Logging in.
Go to Site administration > Plugins > Plugins overview:-its not working
Find the plugin you want to uninstall:-not working
Click the Uninstall link:-not working
Delete the attendance folder and its contents from the mod directory:-Done
Clear Moodle's cache:-Done

Can you switch on debugging and copy and paste the error message and trace into the question please, not a screenshot
Edit config.php and insert these lines
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!


Hi Russell, It's not working..

What isn't working? No error message?
